# Player jump animation bug

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-physics

I am trying to make my first game a 2D platformer, but I ran into an issue that I can not figure out. So I have my character on the floor, and when I am trying to jump, sometimes it jump and play the jump animation, sometimes just jump. I have both instructions(about velocity and animation) in the same if, so I cant really see what is happening there. I will leave the code below if someone can help. I`m also open up for discord or skype calls. Thanks in advance!

Player Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.XR;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour

{
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private PlayerAnimations playerAnim;
    private SpriteRenderer playerSprite;


    //JUMPING
    [SerializeField]
    private float jumpingForce = 4.5f;
    [SerializeField]
    private float movementSpeed = 3;
    private float fallMultiplier = 2f;
    private bool isGrounded = false;

    void Start()
    {

        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        playerAnim = GetComponent<PlayerAnimations>();
        playerSprite = GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer>();

    }

    void Update()
    {
        Movement();
        MeeleAttack();
    }


    void Movement()
    {
        //MOVING
        float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        isGrounded = IsGrounded();
        Flip(horizontalInput);
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(horizontalInput * movementSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
        playerAnim.Move(horizontalInput);

        //JUMPING
        SmootherJump();

    }

    bool IsGrounded()
    {
        RaycastHit2D isGrounded = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.down, 0.3f, 1 << 8);
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, Vector2.down * 0.3f, Color.green);

        if (isGrounded.collider != null)
        {
            playerAnim.Jump(false);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
   
    }

    void SmootherJump()
        {

            if (rb.velocity.y < 0)
            {
                rb.velocity += Vector2.up * Physics2D.gravity.y * (fallMultiplier - 1) * Time.deltaTime;

            }

            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) && IsGrounded() == true)
            {
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpingForce);
                playerAnim.Jump(true);
            }

        }


    void Flip(float horizontalInput)
    {
        if (horizontalInput > 0)
        {
            playerSprite.flipX = false;
        }
        else if (horizontalInput < 0)
        {
            playerSprite.flipX = true;
        }
    }

    void MeeleAttack()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && IsGrounded() == true)
        {
            playerAnim.MeeleAttack();
        }
           

    }

}
```

Player Animation Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerAnimations : MonoBehaviour
{

    private Animator anim;

    void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponentInChildren<Animator>();
    }

    public void Move(float horizontalInput)
    {

        anim.SetFloat("Move", Mathf.Abs(horizontalInput));

    }

    public void Jump (bool jumping)
    {

        anim.SetBool("Jumping", jumping);

    }

    public void MeeleAttack()
    {
        anim.SetTrigger("Meele Attack");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i believe that the fact that you are modifiying the animator

```
bool IsGrounded()
{
    RaycastHit2D isGrounded = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.down, 0.3f, 1 << 8);
    Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, Vector2.down * 0.3f, Color.green);

    if (isGrounded.collider != null)
    {
        playerAnim.Jump(false); ////HEREEEEE
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}
```

here and :

```
void SmootherJump()
    {

        if (rb.velocity.y < 0)
        {
            rb.velocity += Vector2.up * Physics2D.gravity.y * (fallMultiplier - 1) * Time.deltaTime;

        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) && IsGrounded() == true)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpingForce);
            playerAnim.Jump(true); ////HEREEEEE
        }

    }
```

here is creating some kind of conflict. In particular i think that when you jump it detects that you are not grounded anymore and sends a anim.SetBool("Jumping", jumping); that overrides the previous one

Comment: thanks a lot for your time guys, but I solved it with moving ```playerAnim.Jump(true);``` in IsGround function, under the else

Answer (score 0):

What you should be doing is have "Jump" as a [Trigger](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.SetTrigger.html) instead of a Bool and have the animation not loop itself (from the animation inspector itself, not the animator). Then, when you need to jump, just do

```cs
anim.SetTrigger("Jump");
```

and your player's jump animation will play once.

(Since I can't comment) - can you please update your post with a picture of the animator? There might be something wrong there.